# How to find reliable sources of freelance projects abroad?

Tags: foreign-markets

I'm a senior-developer in my company and I have almost a decade of experience in my field. Thanks to some presentation and talk I've given in the past I've been head-hunted for a prestigious job in Japan. I don't speak Japanese well and I don't know how many of the things work here. But long-story short - I want some freelance project and I have the time to do them.

My problem is that I cannot communicate with the local market and if I'd ever want freelance in my own country I'd be able to meet the person and discuss all the details about the project. Also, I haven't been freelancing for about 4 years now so most of my freelance sources are now gone.

My question is - how to find reliable freelance projects from abroad without being able to meet the client in person?

NOTE: I do have a portfolio of pet-projects I've made in my free time as well as showing the large projects I participated in my company.

Comment: see
 http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/struggling-to-find-work
 http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/742/where-to-find-remote-contract-work-in-sap-abap and
http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/how-to-find-web-development-work-outside-the-freelancing-sites

Answer (score 1):

I have not followed those suggested links in the comments to your questions yet, but one idea I had was:

There must be a community or network of expats from your country in Japan. You cannot do business directly if you do not speak the native language, but you can do work for english speaking residents. So target foreign companies in Japan. Your story is very compelling and even though you do not speak Japanese I am sure your services would be very attractive to non-native companies operating in Japan.

Good luck,

Paul.